# type AWS credentials provider has no member credentials with region type

Tags: xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make my app connect to Amazon S3 and retrieve files from a bucket only I'm getting some errors.

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(AWSRegionType.EUWest1,identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId ,unauthRoleArn: unRoleArn, authRoleArn: RoleArn, accoundId: ID )
```

This is the code that is giving me an error with "Type 'AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider' has no member 'CredentialsWithRegionType'" hopefully some can spread some light on what I have been doing wrong because at the moment I don't know if it's something in my code or me not installing the correct things with my Podfile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new, simpler way to provide credentials in swift. Try this and see if it fixes your errors:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId)
```